# Which 4 wheel drive to use to pull boat out of harbor?

Tags: truck, 4wd, boat

I didn't see this asked so thought why not since I'm stuck on which to use.  When pulling a 15ft or more boat out of the harbor while your truck is on the ramp partially in the water and connected to the trailer should you use four wheel drive low or high?

I know from research it says low is great for serious instances but I've never seen it mentioned if it's good on if you're towing.

Answer (score 1):

Go with low : keeps the speed down delivers the power smoothly and you are not in a rush. Had several landrovers one fitted with v8 and a rangerover LT77 gearbox - low gives you control without slipping the clutch.